# "coupled" NSWindows

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I am trying to have "coupled" NSWindows.

I mean 2 NSWindows of the same size, positioned side by side. If I move one, the other one has to move as well to keep both side by side.

I tried to do this with child window but when the child window is moved, the "mother" stays in place.

How I can get this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

Designate an object as the windows' delegate and respond to the `‑windowDidMove:`, `‑windowWillResize:toSize:` and/or `‑windowWillMove:` delegate methods, or register to receive the corresponding notifications. You can then resize the other window as you see fit.

This sounds like an odd UI, by the way. Can you not just use a split view?

Comment: It's for an FTP like application so 2 similar windows for source and target.

Comment: @AP: That doesn't really answer Rob's question. What's wrong with a split view for that?

Comment: @Peter: Take a look at PhotoShop's tool panels, they can be "chained" together. This can't be replaced with a split view.

Comment: @Gobra: Ah, that's a good use case. Some Omni apps do that, too, so it might be worth looking in the Omni frameworks.